# SQL COUNT overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, overflow

Here is my query:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Similarities WHERE T1Similarity = 0 OR T2Similarity = 0`

Here is the result:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

The table has 4 billion rows. I don't expect this query to be fast, but after about 5mins, it fails with an overflow error. Is there a `COUNT` function for bigger data than int?

Thanks.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Use [COUNT_BIG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx)

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM Similarities WHERE T1Similarity = 0 OR T2Similarity = 0
```

Answer (score 26):

```
  SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM Similarities WHERE T1Similarity = 0 OR T2Similarity = 0
```

Comment: I get this answer was posted 1 minute after pstrjds posted theirs, but they're completely identical. Do we need this?